# How can I display the file name with file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show the file name while uploading the file.For that i used the hidden field.
My code is

```
<label>File</lable>
<input type="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg" width="30px"/>
<input type="file" id="my_file" style="display: none;" />
```

javascript is

```
$("input[type='image']").click(function() {
    $("input[id='my_file']").click();
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("input[type='image']").click(function () {
    $("input[id='my_file']").click();
});

$("input[id='my_file']").change(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next().html($this.val().split('\\').pop());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkzfk/3/)

Answer (score 5):

If you just need the filename:

```
$('#my_file').change(function(){
    var filename = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
});
```